# Which link tag to copy from google font out of the three link tags it give?

Tags: html, css

In order to add the google font into the site, it gives 3 link tags after selecting your preferred font. For example, if I want to embed *Merriweather*. The link tags it give are as follows

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

What are these 3 tags? and which one should I copy and paste in my head element?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load them all, and **first two are to preconnect fonts** which improves efficiency resulting in better **SEO** and overall **lighthouse score** for your website.

To use **third** one is obvious.

In short, you **must** use all three.

Example of Eddiehub's website using this [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C3Cm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the third one and then
you have to specify the font-family CSS.
checkout this link
https://codeburst.io/intro-to-google-fonts-for-web-developers-5559b63807d3

Answer (score 0):

In short... You load them all, and the **first two** improve the speed and efficiency of loading font or fonts and, consequently, also improve the performance of Your website.

https://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/faster-google-webfonts-preconnect/

https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#preconnect

The **third one** We do not need to explain ..:-D I hope So :P

I hope this helps You :-) Best Regards !

Answer (score -1):

Html Box With Text Inside - lawlibraries.net
https://www.lawlibraries.net/law/html-box-with-text-inside
html - Keep Text Within The Box - Stack Overflow › Search The Best Law at [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) Law Details: Feb 19, 2012 · You can add overflow-x property, which your text is still within the box, but it will have a scroll bar within this if the content …